# Kafka eventlistener does not working in SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-boot-test

I want to test the reading of events from a kafka topic in a Spring boot te

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("kafka-test")
class EmbeddedKafkaIntegrationTest {

private static final String TOPIC = "my-topic";


private final BlockingQueue<ConsumerRecord<String, MyEvent>> consumptionQueue = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();


@EventListener(condition = "event.listenerId.startsWith('test-listener')")
public void idleEventHandler(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
    log.info(event.toString());
}

@KafkaListener(id = "test-listener", idIsGroup = false, topics = "${beb.topic.prefix}" + TOPIC,
        autoStartup = "true", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
private void listen(ConsumerRecord<String, MyEvent> consumerRecord) throws InterruptedException {
    log.info("Consume key={}, value={}", consumerRecord.key(), consumerRecord.value());
    consumptionQueue.put(consumerRecord);
}
}
```

For some reason the @EventListener is not working. The @KafkaListener works fine. If I put the @EventListener method in one of the application component classes, it also works fine. It just refuses to work within the EmbeddedKafkaIntegrationTest.

I want to use the eventlistener as part of my test conditions.

Comment: You cannot as that only works on spring beans and a test isn't a managed bean, to that I'm actually surpised that the `@KafkaLIstener` seems to work.

Comment: Yes, I don't understand. I moved it to a seperate class to be scanned and it works. @KafkaListener doesn't need it. It works fine. That is the thing I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't show the whole picture of your configuration, but that `@EventListener` has to be moved to the `@Configuration` class. For example, you can add a `@TestConfiguration` in addition to the rest of your Spring Boot configuration involved in this test suite.

I also believe that `@KafkaListener` you show is not a part of that `EmbeddedKafkaIntegrationTest`. Since, as Martin, pointed out it is not supposed to work from a test class by itself. Just because the test class is not a bean for scanning.

See more info in Spring Boot docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing